# Show that there exist $c \in (0,1)$ such that $\vert x \vert < cR$ for all $x \in K$. Is my proof right?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $R>0$ and let $K$ be a compact subset of the interval $(-R,R)$, show that there exist $c \in (0,1)$ such that $\vert x \vert < cR, \ \forall x \in K$

---

**My attempt**

Suppose that for all $c \in (0,1)$ there exists $x_c \in K$ such that $\vert x_c \vert \geq cR$. Then if we consider the sequence $(c_k)$ given by $c_k = 1-\frac{1}{2k}$, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_k \in K$ such that $R > \vert x_k \vert \geq c_k R$. Since $(x_k)$ is bounded and $K$ is compact there exists a subsequence $(x_{k_n})$ such that $x_{k_n} \to L \in K$ so that $\vert x_{k_n} \vert \to \vert L \vert$. Since: $R > \vert x_{k_n} \vert \geq c_k R$ then $\vert L \vert = R$ and therefore $L = R$ or $L=-R$, wich is a contradiction since $-R, R \notin K$.

It would be very helpful if any of you could tell me if my proof is correct, well written and unambiguous.

Comment: That's correct and well-written. There is what seems to be a minor typo: $|x_{k_n}| \geq c_k R$ - it should be $|x_{k_n}| \geq c_{k_n} R$. As an alternative approach straight from definition - you can say that $(-R(1 - 1/n), R(1 - 1/n))$ is an open cover of $K$, thus has finite subcover, which can be reduced to a single interval, and corresponding interval will give you $c$.

Comment: It is correct but a shorter one is: $a:=\sup_{x\in K}|x|$ is attained (since $|~|$ is continuous and $K$ is compact), i.e. $\exists x\in K,a=|x|.$ Therefore, $a<R.$ Now choose any $c\in(a/R,1)$.